# I have questions about how to click and search on web using vba

Tags: excel, vba, web, button, click

I have questions about how to click and search on web using vba.
I have wrote the code, but cannot find how to click the button in this web

```
Sub LEISearch()

    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
    Dim LEI As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
    Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
    Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link'
    Dim result2 As String


    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
    objIE.navigate "https://www.gmeiutility.org/search.jsp?keyWord"

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
    objIE.document.getElementById("searchInput").Value = _
        Sheets("Macro1").Range("A1").Value

    'click the 'go' button
    Set LEIButton = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("hiddenSubmitButton")
    LEIButton.Focus
    LEIButton.Click


    'wait again for the browser
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: There is `.fireevent("click")` you could try, but also if it's in a `form` then the parent form will need to be submitted, by `objIE.document.forms(0).submit` for example, have a look at the HTML to see if there is a form.    Looking at this `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()">Search</button>` may help matters

Answer (score 0):

This case is a really nice and clean example of web scraping so i will take this opportunity to present an educational post.

I highly recommend avoiding using `IE` to scrape websites whenever it's possible. It's highly inefficient. Especially in a case like this where there can be multiple pages of results. Instead, you can use `HTTP requests`.

An HTTP request is a structured way to request something from a server. In this case we want to send a keyword to the server and get the corresponding search results.

To find out how this request should look like, you have to inspect the network traffic when the button with the magnifying glass is clicked. You can do that through your browser's developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+E if you're using Firefox):

[image]

If you go through the Headers and the Params of the request you will see how the url, the body and the headers should look like. In this particular case, all the parameters are encoded into the url and the headers are not essential to the success of the request, so all you need is the url.

Some of the parameters of the url are the keyword, the number of results per page and the number of page.

The response's payload is in json format. You can inspect its structure using a tool like [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Basically the JSON response consists of as many results as you have specified that should be displayed per page (or less). To get the next page you need to send a new request with the same keyword but specifying a new page number and so on.

In fact, as you can see the website offers a lot more data than what's displayed on your browser, which could prove to be useful.

The code below searches for the keyword `test`, while requesting 25 results per page. One first request is sent to find out how many pages of results are there and then the code loops through all pages and prints the results in a worksheet.

**TL;DR**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim totalNumberOfPages As Long
Dim searchResults As Object
Dim pageNumber As Long
Dim results() As String
Dim entity As Object
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet")
''''''First request to find out the number of pages''''''
Set searchResults = XHRrequest("test", 25, 1)           '
totalNumberOfPages = searchResults("totalPages")        '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'''''''''''''''''''Loop through all the pages''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For pageNumber = 1 To totalNumberOfPages Step 1                             '
    Set searchResults = XHRrequest("test", 25, pageNumber)                  '
    ReDim results(1 To searchResults("entitySearchResult").Count, 1 To 7)   '
    i = 0                                                                   '
'''''''''''write the results in an array''''''''''''''''''''''''''''        '
    For Each entity In searchResults("entitySearchResult")         '        '
        i = i + 1                                                  '        '
        results(i, 1) = entity("LEINumber")                        '        '
        results(i, 2) = entity("legalName")                        '        '
        results(i, 3) = entity("city")                             '        '
        results(i, 4) = entity("headquartersCountry")              '        '
        results(i, 5) = entity("recordStatus")                     '        '
        results(i, 6) = entity("renewalStatus")                    '        '
        results(i, 7) = entity("entityStatus")                     '        '
    Next entity                                                    '        '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''        '
'''''''''''''''write all the results in the worksheet in one go'''''        '
    With sht                                                       '        '
        Set rng = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) '        '
    End With                                                       '        '
    rng.Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results   '        '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''        '
Next pageNumber                                                             '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End Sub

Public Function XHRrequest(ByVal key As String, ByVal resultsPerPage As Long, ByVal pageNumber As Long) As Object
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim url As String

url = "https://www.gmeiutility.org/actions/Search/?isPendingValidationChecked=true&isSearchAllLOUChecked=true&keyWord=" & key & "&page=" & pageNumber & "&resultsPerPage=" & resultsPerPage & "&searchType=baseSearch" 'build the URL according to the parameters

'''''''''Send the HTTP request'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
With req                                                    '
    .Open "POST", url, False                                '
    .send                                                   '
    Set XHRrequest = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText) '
End With                                                    '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End Function
```

For demonstration purposes the code above prints all the data in worksheet named `Name of your Worksheet`.

If you need to perform multiple searches you can easily modify the code to best fit your needs. More specifically you can loop through multiple keywords and call the `XHRrequest` function using those keywords instead of "test".

Here's a sample of the output:
[image]

You will need to add the following references to your project (VBE>Tools>References):

```
Microsoft WinHTTP Services version 5.1
Microsoft HTML Objects Library
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
```

You will also need to add this [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to your project. Follow the installation instructions in the link and you should be set to go.

Comment: Hi there, i quite not get your point. can you explain it more detailed

Comment: @mike I am just giving you an alternative, more efficient approach to web scraping. I have explained it quite thoroughly tbh. Is there something specific that you'd want me to explain?

Comment: Cause I cannot ran it properly even if I changed the tab name to exactly what you mentioned I don’t know why

Comment: @mike Did you add the references and the JSON parser? What do you mean you can’t run it properly? Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes, i have added the reference and JSON, it kept getting errors metioning it is out of range, it think it is the problem of set sht

Comment: @mike Have you replaced "Name of your Worksheet" with the actual name of the worksheet to which you want the results to be printed?

Comment: yes, i have changed the name and it shows the same result

Comment: @mike Well then, you are doing something wrong. I can't help you if you don't specify the **exact** problem you're having. What's "the same result" ? The only thing I can do, is to guarantee you that the code above, when implemented correctly, works.

Comment: Hi Stavros, i have changed the code to this 
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LEISHEET")

Comment: My sheet name is LEISHEET, but when i press F8 to this code, it keep telling me run time error 9, script out of range errors. I cannot find any solusions

Comment: It really helped a lot!!!! i am so sorry, i think i should change the name using VBA not just the name in the sheet, now it works, BTW, if it is possible to grab only first 5 result? or if it is possible to click into the first result and grab deeper information?

Comment: Hi Stavors
can you show me how to do multiple searches?